# Commit failed after deleting file

Tags: svn

I'm trying to delete some files from my repository. First, I use 'svn delete *somefile*' after which the file is deleted locally and 'svn status' gives

D *somefile*

as expected. However, if I try to 'svn commit *somefile*' after that, I get the following error:

svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: '*somefile*' is not under version control

I think I made the mistake of deleting the files locally first and so 'svn status' gave me

! *somefile*

which I suspect is the cause of all my troubles now. When I realized my mistake, I thought that I should just checkout a fresh copy and 'svn delete' the files. Clearly that does not work. What I don't understand is if I checkout a fresh copy from the repository, the file is not only present locally, but 'svn status' does not give any indication of there being a problem. To me, that indicates that the repository should be ok, but clearly it is not.

What's the easiest way to fix my problem? (I'm using the svn command-line client version 1.6.17 on Mac OS 10.7.3.)

Answer (score 2):

1. Check out the files again from the SVN in a new folder.
2. Copy the files you were going to commit to the newly checked out
   folder and do the svn add.
3. Commit from the new folder.

Comment: Why do you say 'do svn add'? I'm trying to delete files. When I checkout a fresh copy from the repository, the files I'm trying to delete are present.

Comment: Nick is not referring to the files you want to delete.  He's saying that you should checkout first to ensure that the folder is clean.  Since you might have added files to your other working folder, you'll obviously want to keep them, but you can't commit from that folder.  Therefore, you need to copy these files to your new working folder and add and commit there.  THEN go and svn delete the files you want to get rid of.

Comment: Ok, but I've already added and committed all the files I needed to. When I checkout a fresh copy, that copy is clean as far as I can tell from 'svn status'. I'm having the problem I describe even if I try to 'svn delete' and 'svn commit' from the fresh copy. I'm sorry if I'm missing something you're trying to get across.

Comment: I've found out what was wrong. It was wrong of me to specify the file name when committing after deleting. Instead of 'svn commit -m "some text" _somefile_, I should have just typed 'svn commit -m "some text".

Answer (score 1):

`svn delete <somefile>` -> deletes the files from your local folder

`svn add <somefile>` -> marks the file as "added" in your local folder

`svn commit` -> sends all the changes to your svn repository

If you do  `svn commit <somefile>` you want to commit the changes in a path that SVN doesn't known about, since were never added.

If you have problems try to do an `svn cleanup`, otherwise do a fresh cleanup and start your changes again.